# How can I link to the welcome page declared in the web.xml?

Tags: glassfish, web.xml

I have declared a welcome page in my web.xml file on a local Glassfish 3.1.2 server, like this:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Now, I would like to be able to link to this welcome file from my error page (which is displayed anywhere all across the website). That's the catch: I don't know from which path it will be referred to. It could be `localhost:8080/App/`, or `localhost:8080/App/web/.../`, ...

Is it possible to have one universal link, ignoring what the current directory is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href="/NAME_OF_YOUR_PROJECT/index.jsp">Click Here</a>
```

You have to substitute NAME_OF_YOUR_PROJECT with the name of your web application e.g. "App".

This should refer to the file `index.jsp` in your `WEB-INF` folder.

Comment: Wow, that was way too easy. Thanks!