# Why can't I see my site, and get HTTP Status 404?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, http-status-code-404, status

I'm doing servlet using spring mvc and I can't see my site. I've posted my web.xml, mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml and controller class below. Everything seems to be fine, but when I enter "localhost:8080" I get `404 http status
The requested resource is not available`. Did I miss something?

web.xml:

```
<web-app version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Weather</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.springapp.mvc"/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="defaultPersistenceUnit"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController
{
    Weather weather;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String infoWeather(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest req) {

        if (!model.containsAttribute("location") && !model.containsAttribute("weather")) {
            Language.getInstance().setLanguage(LanguageManager.getLanguage(new Locale(System.getProperty("user.language"))));
            Location location = LocationManager.getLocation(req);
            model.addAttribute("location", location);
            weather = WeatherManager.getWeather(location);
            model.addAttribute("weather", weather);
        }

        if (!model.containsAttribute("destination"))
            model.addAttribute("destination", new Destination());

        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String findDestination(@ModelAttribute("destination") Destination destination, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
        destination = DestinationManager.getDestination(destination.getAddress());
        weather = WeatherManager.getWeather(destination);
        redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("weather", weather);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

Comment: It's very possible your application has a context path on your servlet container. So you wouldn't access it at `localhost:8080/` but at `localhost:8080/that-path`.

Comment: Check the Tomcat instance your application is running and its `server.xml` file. Towards the bottom, you will find a `<Context>` entry for your application.

Comment: i cant find it
here my project tree `http://oi39.tinypic.com/141mnb6.jpg`

Comment: It won't be in your project. Tomcat is the servlet container. Intellij is managing it outside of your application. But right click your project, the context path is probably in properties somewhere.

Comment: found it it looks like this: `http://pastebin.com/78xx3KRq`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see below points here, which needs to be fixed:

1. Once you deploy your application in tomcat webapp directory, the URL should be something like `http://localhost:8080/<web-app-name>/<your servlet>`
2. Alternatively you could add a welcome page and check if it is working. For that you need to add welcome page setting in web-xml. See [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417187/how-can-i-link-to-the-welcome-page-declared-in-the-web-xml) for a clue.

If this is not working, please share your tomcat directory tree with your war deployed; and the war file directory structure

Note: you should be able to expand your war using a zip utility.

Comment: here is the war file `E:\IntelliJ Projects\What2Wear\target`
and here is tomcat
: `E:\IntelliJ Projects\apache-tomcat-7.0.37`

http://oi44.tinypic.com/3039qo5.jpg

Comment: Have you deployed your war in the tomcat and restarted the tomcat? Your war is in target location of the workspace, but you need to add it to tomcat server. If the tomcat server is configured inside the workspace, you may try finding Add/Remove module kind of menu. Otherwise, copy the war from work location, paste into tomcat's webapps location and start the server manaully. Also, looks for the logs when server is starting, the war deployment should be successful in order to access your web-pages and servlets.

Comment: my server logs:
`[2013-09-05 06:50:30,869] Artifact What2Wear_SpringMVC:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
wrz 05, 2013 6:50:31 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(E:\IntelliJ Projects\What2Wear\target\What2Wear\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
[2013-09-05 06:50:32,364] Artifact What2Wear_SpringMVC:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully`

Comment: ok i found a solution i change artificat to deplay and now it works thanks